# QTP/UFT Re-use object variable in functions

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I assigned an object to variable "abc" in function.vbs script

I have a test named "Action1" where I have a function named **xyz()**.

function.vbs is associated with test "Action1".

Running the test throws an error "object doesn't support this property or method"

If I use single extension, it works fine
    `abc.JavaMenu("title:=file").select`

If I use more than one extension to object throw an error "object doesn't support this property or method"
    `abc.JavaMenu("title:=file").JavaMenu("title:=view").select`

```
Set abc = JavaWindow("title:=test")
Function xyz()
  abc.JavaMenu("title:=file").JavaMenu("title:=view").select
End Function
```

Comment: Have you checked that it works with `JavaWindow("title:=test").JavaMenu("title:=file").JavaMenu("title:=view").select` before you assume the problem is with the object assignation?

Comment: Note:- Function xyz() exists in separate file function.vbs which I load during the test run. Yes. I checked. It works if I use the complete path in function.vbs and also it works if I have the function inside the test.

Comment: Have you tried passing `abc` into the function by reference? i.e. `Function xyz(ByRef abc)` to start the function and ensure that the object is accessible to the function?